# Why does my output go to next line when there is no next line character in the script

Tags: perl, scripting

I am learning & writing a very basic Perl script as follows:-

```
print "Please enter your name dear: ";
$name = <STDIN>;
print "${name} you are learning Perl";
```

For some reason, output is displayed as:-

```
Please enter your name dear: saas
saas
 you are learning Perl
```

Why does the text after input name go to next line character when there isn't \n mentioned anywhere?

Comment: `perl -e 'print $x= <STDIN>' | hexdump -C`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print "Please enter your name dear: ";
$name = <STDIN>;
chomp $name;
print "${name} you are learning Perl";
```

Notice line 3.  When you send "saas" to  you must press enter to send it.  Newline is appended to your name variable.  Chomp will remove this for you

Comment: Perl doesn't append anything. You append it by pressing `Enter`.

Comment: Yet it still says it's being appended to the variable. Nothing is ever appended to `$name`. STDIN just returns the characters typed which includes Enter (the newline).

Answer (score 5):

There's a newline output where the contents of `$name` is output! Could it be that it's in `$name`? Think about what you typed. Did you type `saas`? No. You typed `saas` + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Use `chomp` to remove the trailing newline from `$name`.

Comment: I typed plain saas without any spaces pre /post.

Comment: No, you didn't. Like I said, you typed `saas` followed by Enter. That's more than just `saas`. What effect do you suppose Enter has?

Comment: I expected to display the output as 'saas you are learning Perl., chomp fulfilled my expectation.. Thanks ikegami...

Comment: I know what you want the output to be. Not sure why you mentioned that?